# What is the generic term for a thing that is being 'replied to'?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I 'reply' to something (a person, an email, etc.), the thing I produce through the action is a 'reply' (or a 'response'). Is there a generic term (noun) for the thing that the reply/response is replying to?

For some more context, I'm trying to choose a word for a database column for the 'parent' of a comment which is a reply to another comment (ie the next in the comment thread). This also implies a chain of comments rather than a bunch of comments all referring to a single 'conversation root'.

An example (that has a very obvious non-generic answer) would be: As you navigate through the conversation tree of comments, click the 'back' link to view the ___________ to which that particular reply was in response.

Some examples that I'm not (entirely) happy with:

- original_comment
- parent
- reply_to

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! A good question! [single-word-requests] require a sample sentence, e.g. "When I poke a jelly and it moves after a wavy fashion, it is _____.", to which the answer might be "wobbling". Please edit your question to include such a phrase.

Comment: You can reply to *a comment, a post, a response, a reply, a message, an utterance, an intervention, a turn* in the series, something that was *written, a transaction* -- and if none of those appeal to you you might get some more ideas by putting some of those into a thesaurus.

Comment: To view the previous comment in this thread...

Answer (score 1):

Is it not a ***request***?

The person replying is a ***respondent***, and the information they give is a ***response***.

And to what do I *respond*, with a *response* - surely a *request*.

Comment: I don't know about you but in a typical day I respond to plenty of things that are not requests.

Comment: @AntonSherwood You make a valid point. We "respond" to many things - initiatives, suggestions, proposals, actions, comments etc. (as well as requests) and I don't know that there is any generic term that encompasses the types of things to which you respond.

Answer (score 0):

I have two synonyms to consider, both of which strongly suggest the idea that the item *comes before* the reply.

**[Antecedent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antecedent)**

> 1. Any thing that precedes another thing, especially the cause of the second thing.
> 2. An ancestor.

"Antecedent" also has several specific uses in math, logic, and grammar. Personally, I would find that interference about as distracting as the word "parent."

For that reason I prefer **[precursor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precursor)**.

> That which precurses: a forerunner, predecessor, or indicator of approaching events.

So an initial comment may be the precursor or antecedent of a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Predecessor

From an English language & usage point of view, TaliesinMerlin is absolutely right - *antecedent* is near perfect. But from the point of view of a developer choosing a column name, both "antecedent" and "precursor" are very clumsy, so I would use *predecessor*.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation_threading).

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a word for a specific node in a thread.